# Is it efficient to use css frameworks? If so, which one is best? Or any comparison comments?

Tags: css, frameworks, css-frameworks

Is it efficient to use css frameworks? 
If so, which one is best? 
Or any comparison comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really it depends on your individual skills, preferences, and work style - for some people, it's faster to just work from scratch rather than trying to conform to someone else's design methodology; for others having a basic framework in place speeds things up tremendously. You really just have to try it both ways and see which works out better for you.

The "best" question is rather subjective, I don't think there's a single answer for that.

Comment: //The "best" question is rather subjective
Agreed. Asking question itself is an art... :-)
Thanks for that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that is a bit of an overkill. You are better off using something like jQuery (and the jQuery plugins) and achieve the effects you want with more control and space for customization.

Comment: I asked about CSS framework. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I feel a full framework is a bit much. My CSS structure usually looks something like this:

I start by grabbing YUI's reset.css (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) and base.css (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/base/), throw them into a single file and call this file first on every page.

Next I create a file called structure.css. This file is strictly for any global page layout styles allowing me to keep structure separate from style.

Lastly I will create style.css and this contains all page coloring, non-global layout code and other miscellaneous styles.

Answer (score 0):

For my money, it isn't worth it. It can be helpful when building a site from scratch but If, like me, you work with CMS systems a lot then they tend to be more trouble than they're worth.